# Fastest way for webscraping a page implementing a shopping bot

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, scrapy, http-post, bots

My friend and I are trying to develop a shopping bot. It must be as fast as it can get, because the products might run out of stock in a matter of seconds. We have looked for different ways of doing this, and we came up with Selenium and Scrapy and other python libraries, and we have something working already, but it seems so slow doing the task at hand.

We have thought of instead of scraping the web page (selecting product, adding to cart, etc), try making a bot that just sends an HTML post requests to the server of the store with the product and the rest of the information necessary. We have read in other posts that this is done with the requests library, but how can we know what information and how many post requests does an action require (like for example clicking the add to cart button sends some posts request to the server, so how can we know the information that goes in that request to emulate it in our program?)

We would like the library to be able to scrape web pages with JavaScript, for example when clicking a button or selecting an item from a drop down menu. We have run across some libraries that weren't able to do it (such as Scrapy)

Also we would appreciate if you know of a different programming language with may be better libraries or that it executes faster, we both know Python and Java, but we are open to suggestions

Comment: Not sure that you can make API, because you probably need authorization. Public open API exist, but I do not think that you are lucky.

Answer (score 0):

the fastest way would be through [requests](https://pypi.org/project/requests/), using bs4 or regex to scrape the web page, this is what most 'shopping bots' use, to make it even faster you could write the bot in go or typescript which are way faster then python

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I read about bs4 or rejex, but the problem is that most of the web pages we want to use the bot for, use javascript, and Im not sure those libraries support it (for example when clicking a button to access a different par of the website). Do you think we should use something different or any of those libraries should work?

Comment: regex works well for scraping the js part